TypeError: Cannot read property 'explorerPage' of undefined
I am upgrading jest from version 23 to 29. My project used to work fine before the upgrade, suddenly started observing this issue. I use Typescript as a language.
TestPageDefs Module looks like below:
import { lxExplorer } from "../pageObjects/explorer/lxExplorer.pom";
export class TestPageDefs {

  // Page object files
  public static explorerPage: lxExplorer = new lxExplorer();

}

This is consumed in another module/class.
import { TestPageDefs } from "../../helpers/TestPageDefs";

export class lxLinkAnalysis extends  BasePluginPage<lxLinkAnalysis> {

public  ebsLinkClassifyCountQuery: string = TestPageDefs.explorerPage.ebsTableQuery + " | link    'Log Source' | classify Count";
}

Getting below error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'explorerPage' of undefined


I did tried other import like default or all imports (*). Nothing helped.

Are you sure that ../../helpers/TestPageDefs is the right module with the TestPageDefs named export?

Yes, as I am able to navigate to TestPageDefs by Pressing control and clicking on  ../../helpers/TestPageDefs.

Thanks @Phil for looking into it and all helps are greatly appreciated.

It seems to be working with ts-jest 28 but not with ts-jest 29.
